# How to manage images in a cross-platform app?

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm creating cross platform demo project but i stuck with a problem when trying debug app on ios symulator. First i couldn't pair my mac to visual studio but i just send all files as rar and open on mac. Android project is all fine but when trying to launch on iphone simulator app throw exception that

```
System Exception : Image: file"bgtest5.jpg" not found in app bundle.
```

(Android version is working all fine on this mac). According to my question i put all images my app need to load in resources folder in ios solution , mark them as "bundleResources", i see on debuger output that my observablecollection is in read and then exception is thrown about image...

MyModel class

```
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PersonBackgroundImage { get; set; }
    public double ProgressCounter { get; set; }
```

ListViewModel class

```
            var personList = new List<PersonViewModel>
        {
             new PersonViewModel()
            {
                Name="Test", Surname="Test", Description= "TEsT", Background = "bgtest6.jpg", ProgressCounter =0.1, SavedClicked=0,Weight=1
            },
            new PersonViewModel()
            {
                Name="Test", Surname="Test", Description= "TEsT",Background = "bgtest6.jpg", ProgressCounter =0.1, SavedClicked=0,Weight=30
            },
            new PersonViewModel()
            {
                Name="Test", Surname="Test", Description= "TEsT",Background = "bgtest6.jpg", ProgressCounter =0.2, SavedClicked=0
            },
            new PersonViewModel()
            {
                Name="Test", Surname="Test", Description= "TEsT",Background = "bgtest6.jpg", ProgressCounter =0.3, SavedClicked=0,Weight=27
            },
        };
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>(personList);
```

PersonPage

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CommandDemo.Views.PersonPage"
         BackgroundImage="{Binding Person.Background}">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Person.Description}"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="Medium"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Person.ProgressCounter}"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="Medium"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

MyListPage

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CommandDemo.Views.PersonListPage"
         BackgroundImage="bgtest5.jpg">
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Text="Numbers"
                Command="{Binding NavigateSumPageCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10"
                 Margin="10">
        <ListView x:Name="personList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  >
            <!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"-->
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                      Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference personList},Path=BindingContext.NavigateCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                            <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding ProgressCounter}"/>
                            <Button Text="Add Progress"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference personList},Path=BindingContext.IncreaseProgressCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Label Text="{Binding SumCollected}"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding PieceCollected}"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Button Text="Numbers"
                Command="{Binding NavigateSumPageCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

All bindings works as excpected on android project. Ios project coudn't be loaded due to exception thrown at loading an app. Am I missing some value converter for images working on ios project or what ? For any help with this or guide how to achive my goals i would be very appreciated ! :) Thank you in advance

Edit:1
After deleting line BackgroundImage = "bgtest5.jpg" project loaded on white background and all binded images are showing right now. Where is a problem ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos

Comment: i follow this and just posted my result :(

Comment: have you verified that the image is not corrupt?  Have you tried removing and re-adding the image?

Comment: And are you sure about the extension?

Comment: i know that when i load an image with jpg extension app all crash with exception i wrote , but if i load app with some png image as background everythings is fine except sizes which i have to have prepered for iso :)